# XULrunner permissions for loading remote XUL

Tags: xulrunner

I would like to use just PHP (via local AMPPS server) to generate all of my XUL. It appears that XULrunner will not allow one to load a "remote" URL (ie. `http://mylocaldomain.com`).

I have done a fair amount of searching and I see replies that look like an answer but they are vague or quite old, and I am unable to get them to work. What I think is a relevant answer is to use [nsIPermissionManager](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIPermissionManager), there is an example at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_Remote_XUL but I am unable to get it to work

```
Components.classes["@mozilla.org/permissionmanager;1"]
    .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPermissionManager)
    .add('http://www.mylocaldomain.com/', 'allowXULXBL', Components.interfaces.nsIPermissionManager.ALLOW_ACTION);
```

I have tried loading it in the `pref.js` as well as at the beginning of my `main.js` and neither works. If I place it in my `main.js` file the Error Console in XULrunner gives this error

> Error: NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS: Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsIPermissionManager.add]

and If I run it in Firefox I get this error

> TypeError: Components.classes is undefined

I also found this post here, [Is it possible to reference remote content from chrome.manifest? (XULRunner)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661332/is-it-possible-to-reference-remote-content-from-chrome-manifest-xulrunner) which basically looks to have you place the `application.ini` and the `defaults\preferences\prefs.js` on your server and run them from there. So if I run my app with `"...\xulrunner.exe" -app http://www.mylocaldomain.com/application.ini -jsconsole` XULrunner just says it can't parse the `application.ini`.

So the question how does one setup in XULrunner to allow the use of a remote URL?

**Edit: Round 2** (well more like round 50 but who's counting)

It is amazing that there isn't a single tutorial on remote XUL. I bought a book [Introductory XUL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005U76PDO) not word in the whole book about remote XUL. Yea I could have bought a a different book, but as age goes, the next one on the list was from 2007, before Mozilla mutilated the XULrunner.

With the book idea having failed I though there's an Add-on, [Remote XUL Manager](https://github.com/jvillalobos/Remote-XUL-Manager). Let just dissect it. Out of its almost 1000 lines of code it looks like it takes 2 lines to set a permission for a remote URL.

In [permissions.js](https://github.com/jvillalobos/Remote-XUL-Manager/blob/master/extension/modules/permissions.js) at lines 97 you have

```
Services.perms.add(uri, ALLOW_REMOTE_XUL, ALLOW);
```

and line 143 you have

```
Services.io.newURI(aDomainString, null, null);
```

Put together and variables replaced you get

```
var uri = Services.io.newURI('http://www.mylocaldomain.com', null, null);
Services.perms.add(uri, "allowXULXBL", 1);
```

To run it, it looks like you need to add this before it

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
```

But upon running that in XULrunner I get this error

> TypeError: Components.utils is undefined

same as before. So a bit of googling and I found I need this

```
netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalXPConnect");
```

so I added it to the top of my code and got this error

> TypeError: netscape.security.PrivilegeManager is undefined

And if you google for `xulrunner "netscape.security.PrivilegeManager is undefined"` you get 4 results (with this post I guess it will now be 5). Fortunately, if remove `xulrunner` you get more results and a bit of reading between the lines it appears that  `netscape.security.PrivilegeManager` is obsolete ([obsolete reference](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/953743)).

On one of my searches `xulrunner "Components.utils is undefined"` (again 4 results) turned up a post here on SO, [Firefox Add-on SDK and js-ctypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22136130/firefox-add-on-sdk-and-js-ctypes). Based on that I tried this

```
const {Cu} = require('chrome');
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");

var uri = Services.io.newURI('http://www.mylocaldomain.com', null, null);
Services.perms.add(uri, "allowXULXBL", 1);
```

Which gives this error

> ReferenceError: require is not defined

I appears that doing this is possible as there is an Add-on doing it, and looks like its just a couple lines but what those line are appears to be a secret more closely guarded that nuclear launch codes.

So back to hunting down every last little rabbit trail and discovering more dead-ends, at least till someone is willing to spill the beans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is an Oh duh moment. But as I have seen a lot of these posts go unanswered I am going to post the answer.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<?xml-stylesheet href="main.css" type="text/css"?>

<window id="main" title="My App" xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

    <vbox flex="1">
        <browser id="mainbrowser" src="http://www.mylocaldomain.com/main.xul" flex="1" />
    </vbox>

</window>
```

It truly is that simple. **The browser element is very powerful and can run XUL from any URL** with no extra configuration needed. Note there is no javascript above, and as for my `pref.js`, it is just the one preference needed to start my local `main.xul`, and then the 5 extra options that help with debugging. I would even remove the stylesheet but, at the moment, it looks like there is a bug that forces XULrunner into fullscreen mode when I remove it.

I have been looking at this issue and building work arounds for the last 2+ months. I can't believe all the time I wasted on something that had such a simple solution.